# Crystal Reports repeating Group header in section

Tags: crystal-reports

When I use group headers / footers in SAP, the group header returns for each line, causing it to create duplicate headers.

For example - in Group Header 2 I have the following fields: Item Group, Total usage, On Hand Qty, Avg Cost, On hand cost and Days on Hand.

What I would like to see is just that header once, instead of being repeated multiple times for each record, screenshot below:

[screenshot of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck7sy.png)

Here is an image of the report structure
[report structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hZWI.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by 'item group'. 
When it changes it will print the header again. Group on something else if that's possible.